# C# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (NullReferenceException)

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I have written a very simple code in console application. I have created a static class i.e.

```
public static class A
{
 public static void GetData(Int16 Id)
 {
  //method code
 }
}
```

and I'm trying to call this method in main method i.e.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A.GetData(21);
        }
    }
```

but I'm getting this error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
**Note:** class "A" is in another project (within same solution) and I have added the reference of this project in startup (main) project.
any solution please?

Comment: you need to create a new instance of  `A`

Comment: Can you please provide minimum, verifiable, complete example? First suggestion is that exception is thrown inside method `A.GetData`

Comment: Where are you getting the null pointer? In the GetData() call or inside it?

Comment: The problem lies into the body of your GetData method

Comment: @styx thanks for sharing. But "A" is a static class and i think it doesn't need to instantiate it.

Comment: @АндрейСаяпин thanks for suggestion dear. I have also tried with empty body of method "GetData()".

Comment: @fsbflavio thanks for asking. it doesn't go inside of this method. It throw exception as it tries to call this method.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar thanks for the link, I had visited before posting this question.

Comment: @kalitsov thanks for help but I have tried it with empty body too.

Comment: @JamesHill thaks for your comment, please can you specify it a little bit more, what kind of modification should I do in class A?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with the code that you posted. If you're getting a null reference exception you're either:

- Missing a using statement that points to where your static A class lives (you said that you've already included this.
- Your `GetData()` method is throwing the null ref exception. This is the most likely scenario. A quick debugging session will answer the question for you.

I've created a quick and dirty [.net fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/O6bTvl) to demonstrate that your code, at least what you posted, is working properly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, basically I'm getting multiple connection strings through configuration manager  in class A (at class level) and putting them in string variable like this:

static string CS1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;
static string CS2 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS2"].ConnectionString;
static string CS3 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS3"].ConnectionString;

when I remove this code then application works fine.

Comment: That's gerat news, @HasnainLatif. I'm glad I was able to point you in the right direction! I noticed that you've never marked any answers as the correct/accepted answer for any of the questions you've asked. Marking an answer as the accepted answer is a great way of showing appreciation to all the folks that have helped you out. May I suggest that you go through all the questions you've asked and click the accept check when someone has answered your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Oh, i never thought that people notice this thing. Thanks for telling me I really appreciate it and sure I'll vote from now.

Comment: @HasnainLatif, I figured you didn't - no problem at all! Don't forget to click the check mark too!

Comment: @HasnainLatif, just wanted to follow up. Take a look at this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work, and go back through the questions you've asked. You're missing a step - accepting an answer.